# Unable to delete some Sitecore 8 extranet users

Tags: security, sitecore

Our network operations center ran a security scan on our sites and inadvertently created a lot of extranet user accounts in our Sitecore instance. Some I can just delete using the User Manager. Some I cannot. The issue I'm looking at right now, for example...I have one user selected in the User Manager. When I click delete, I get a dialog asking me if I'm sure I want to delete these 5 users. Another one I was looking at earlier, when I try to delete the user (extranet\ ns:netsparker056650=vuln), I get a "cannot delete this user" message and when I look in the log files and the user name is split onto to lines like

extranet\
ns:netsparker056650=vuln

Not sure what the fastest/best way to remove these users is.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think deleting users would be a better choice, rather you should mark it disable to improve audit purposes.

Disable Netsparker and try again.

Quick way is, You can disable/delete users using PowerShell script. If you are not using PS, use SQL queries in core DB.

References:

https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5983/bulk-deleting-sitecore-users

https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/appendix/commands/Remove-User.html

https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/appendix/commands/Disable-User.html